# set root height as child height

Tags: html, css

I am new in html and css. I try to design web page but have problem with background color of root div.
my code is a little complicated but i try to convert to sample problem.
here is my code.

```
    <style>

#background{
    background-color:#F78F91;
    width:800px;
    min-height:20px;
}

.content{
    min-width:50px;
    max-width:150px;
    min-height:30px;
    max-height:500px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#1860DF;
    border-bottom-color:#D9F733;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
}

</style>

<body>
<div id="background">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to background have same height as child div.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:table` to `#background`:

```
#background{
    background-color:#F78F91;
    width:800px;
    min-height:20px;
    display: table;/*Add this*/
}
```

[**fiddle with table**](http://jsfiddle.net/SfckV/1/)

Alternative just use `float:left`:

```
#background{
    background-color:#F78F91;
    width:800px;
    min-height:20px;
    float: left;/*Add this*/
}
```

[**fiddle with float**](http://jsfiddle.net/SfckV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

add 'overflow:hidden;' to your background css:

```
#background{
  background-color:#F78F91;
  width:800px;
  min-height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```